# Login system not working cant find verifylogin.php - 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

To create the login system i have been using this tutorial - www.codefactorycr.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html. The problem is when i enter the username and password from my database into the form and click login it comes up with a 404 error page and cannot find verifylogin.php. I have included all my files below but i still cant figure out why this is not logging in to the home.php

Autoload.php

```
        Prototype:
        $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'xmlrpc');


        $autoload['libraries'] = array();
```

routes.php

```
          $route['login'] = "login";
          $route['news/update/(:num)'] = 'news/update/$1';
          $route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
          $route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
          $route['news'] = 'news';
          $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
          $route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

config.php

```
          $config['base_url']   = 'http://shaek.co.uk/codeigniter';
          $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Controller - login.php

```
               <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

               class Login extends CI_Controller {

                function __construct()
                {
                    parent::__construct();
                }

                 function index()
                 {
                    $this->load->helper(array('form'));
                    $this->load->view('login_view');
                 }

              }

           ?>
```

Controller - verifylogin.php

```
         <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

      class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

           function __construct()
           {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
              }

          function index()
                   {
         //This method will have the credentials validation
             $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password',      'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

         if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
              {
       //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
          $this->load->view('login_view');
          }
             else
             {
              //Go to private area
             redirect('home_view', 'refresh');
            }

            }

            function check_database($password)
            {
                //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
                  $username = $this->input->post('username');

               //query the database
                    $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

                if($result)
         {
                 $sess_array = array();
                foreach($result as $row)
       {
               $sess_array = array(
               'id' => $row->id,
                username' => $row->username
     );
              $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
            }
              return TRUE;
           }
              else
           {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
             return false;
           }
          }
         }
       ?>
```

Controller home.php

```
            <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
       session_start(); //we need to call PHP's session object to access it through CI
       class Home extends CI_Controller {

              function __construct()
            {
              parent::__construct();
            }

              function index()
            {
              if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
            {
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
            $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
           }
               else
              {
                 //If no session, redirect to login page
                   redirect('login', 'refresh');
               }
             }

                 function logout()
             {
                $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
                session_destroy();
                redirect('home', 'refresh');
              }

           }

        ?>
```

Model - users.php

```
              <?php
                 Class User extends CI_Model
              {
                function login($username, $password)
              {
                 $this -> db -> select('id, username, password');
                 $this -> db -> from('users1');
                 $this -> db -> where('username', $username);
                 $this -> db -> where('password', MD5($password));
                 $this -> db -> limit(1);

                 $query = $this -> db -> get();

                 if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
           {
                    return $query->result();
                  }
             else
              {
                    return false;
            }
        }
     }
   ?>
```

Views - home_view.php

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
      <title>Simple Login with CodeIgniter - Private Area</title>
      </head>
        <body>
          <h1>Home</h1>
               <h2>Welcome <?php echo $username; ?>!</h2>
                <a href="home/logout">Logout</a>
            </body>
             </html>
```

views - login_view.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
   <title>Simple Login with CodeIgniter</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Simple Login with CodeIgniter</h1>
     <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
      <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
       <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
       <br/>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
      <br/>
       <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
            </form>
         </body>
         </html>
```

Comment: try by changing form_open('verifylogin/index')

Comment: If you read the below responses, you will find that http://shaek.co.uk/codeigniter/index.php/verifylogin itself is not accessible. Adding index ahead will do no good.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1'; 
//((:any) will match a segment containing any character.) 
//and throw it to pages/view/$1
```

I recommend changing it to

```
$route['pages/view/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

http://shaek.co.uk/codeigniter/index.php/verifylogin is itself giving a 404 page

Also, http://shaek.co.uk/codeigniter/index.php/pages/view/ is not accessible. The internal routing is causing the request to be passed to pages controller view action.

Comment: i changed the route to $route['pages/view/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1'; still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, you will also have to change your model class name to "Users" as opposed to "User".

---

**Not necessary as noted by Jaspal:**

You have a Controller/class name issue.

If you name your controller "verifylogin.php", you must name the class **the same thing** with a capital **first letter only**. You named your class "VerifyLogin". It must be "Verifylogin".

Comment: That works just as well. In codeigniter "Class names must start with an uppercase letter" it is not mandatory that they do not have any other uppercase characters.

Comment: @JaspalSingh, you're right, good call. However the second part regarding the model is correct.

Comment: I have renamed my class to Verifylogin and model class to User but still same error i cant login in to the form. 404 error

Comment: I might advise ditching the "login" route entirely. Codeigniter creates default routes as base_url/controller/method without you having to manually put these in the config file. Only uses routes when you need to change a URL with parameters.

Comment: if i remove the the login route i get an unexpected error on the login page

Comment: It could be an .htaccess issue. Do you have an .htaccess file in the root directory?

Comment: im not sure. last time i played around with a .htaccess file my whole webserver stopped working

Comment: That could be a problem haha. Check your server, see if there is an .htaccess file, and update your question to include it. It could be causing the issues here.

Answer (score 0):

Change "`Controller - verifylogin.php`" class name from VerifyLogin to Verifylogin and see if it works.

It seems its not able to find the controller name and it could be due to class name.

One more thing in `verifylogin.php` you have missed out a "'" before usename.
change from:

```
 $sess_array = array(
               'id' => $row->id,
                username' => $row->username

);
```

To:

```
 $sess_array = array(
               'id' => $row->id,
                'username' => $row->username

);
```

Comment: i have input the missing "" and changed controller name to Verifylogin still 404 page cannot be found